# html select element sends value to server without value attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question just out of curiosity, I have an HTML select inside of a form that looks like this:

```
<select id="new_office_location_select"  name="newList[#].Value1">
        <option>New York, US</option>
        <option>Stamford, US</option>
        <option>London, UK</option>
        <option>Sydney, AU</option>
</select>
```

when I submit the form, whichever option I have selected sends it's value to the server to my action method, even though I have not set a "value" attribute for each option. This is fine for me, I'm glad its working without it, but don't the option elements theoretically need a "value" attribute?

Comment: Browsers are often smart enough to accommodate non-standard markup. Here, they're using the text value in lieu of a value attribute.

Comment: because you have no value='' attribute

Comment: If no value is set, the spec says that the textContent of the element will be used instead, so this is expected behaviour, and it's cross-browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)

**value**

> The textual content of this attribute represents the label explaining
>   the option. If it is not defined, its default value is the text
>   content of the element.

Comment: @AlexChar you can use @ and the user's name to have your comment notify them.